# Increase decrease arrows & % change in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need some help with a Google spreadsheet. I want to show a up/down arrow and a x% change next to the number within the cell (green if increased & red is decreased) from the cell above.

Here's the YouTube video for reference https://youtu.be/SFU5ZlHUdH0

Hope someone can help. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is basically the same as in your video. In order to put ▲▼ into the clipboard copy the arrows from my answer. Or you can use MS Excel or MS Word to put the arrows to the clipboard and same way they show in your video.

Then in the spreadsheet, select the percentage cells and click `Format-> Number-> More Formats-> Custom Number Format...` and type in the same format as on your video.

Comment: Thank you Andrej for your prompt reply. However, I'm unable to keep the number and also show the % change as shown in the video. I'm using Google Sheets.

Comment: @user, I just was able to do it in Google Sheets. May you describe what exactly do you do; what exactly happens and what exactly you expect to happen?

Comment: @user5621402, have you prepared the data in Delta/Change column as they have in the beginning of the video or you need help with preparing that data?

Comment: Thank you Andrej, I've managed to get this sorted. Appreciate your replies and help.